# Initialize Bootstrap DatePicker in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of timekeeper with edit button in ASP.NET MVC. When edit button is clicked, it will show a modal form. In modal form we should fill the rate, start date and end date.

I'm using bootstrap datepicker for start date and end date, and these was initialized in Index View, but it won't display in modal form when I clicked start date and end date textboxes. What is the problem?

Index View:

```
<div id="timeKeeperList">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_IndexList", Model.TimeKeepers); }
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="timeKeeperModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="timeKeeperContainer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#timeKeeperList").on("click", ".modalTimeKeeper", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $("#timeKeeperContainer").html(data);
                    $("#timeKeeperModal").modal(show = true, backdrop = false);
                });
            });

            $(".date").datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                todayBtn: "linked",
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true
            });
        });

        function editTimeKeeperComplete(data) {
            $("#timeKeeperModal").modal("hide");
        }
    </script>
}
```

IndexList View:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.TimeKeeperID })" class="modalTimeKeeper">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeKeeperNo)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rate)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    TimeKeeper timeKeeper = db.TimeKeepers.Find(id);
    TimeKeeperViewModel timeKeeperVM = new TimeKeeperViewModel()
    {
        TimeKeeperID = timeKeeper.TimeKeeperID,
        Name = timeKeeper.Name,
        EliteRate = timeKeeper.Rate,
        StartDate = timeKeeper.BillingStartDate,
        EndDate = timeKeeper.BillingEndDate,
    };

    return PartialView("_Edit", timeKeeperVM);
}
```

Edit View

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Timekeeper</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="EliteRate" class="control-label">Rate</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="StartDate" class="control-label">Start Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="EndDate" class="control-label">End Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnClose">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your controls for `StartDate` and `EndDate` do not exist when the view is rendered (`$(".date").datepicker({..` does not do anything since there are no controls with `class="date")`. You need to attach the plugin when create the modal.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see, but I don't clear about the plugin that you mean.

Comment: The date picker plugin - you need to do `$(".date").datepicker({..` after the controls with `class=".date"` are added to the DOM (in the `$.get(..` call)